# How to filter an array an array while checking the value of an input?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I'm having an issue while trying to filter my array (see below), i'm trying to filter my recipes while checking if an ingredient is inside a recipe.

You'll find a minimalist example of my problem below.
First the JSON

```
{"recipes": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name" : "Limonade de Coco",
        "servings" : 1,
        "ingredients": [
            {
                "ingredient" : "Lait de coco",
                "quantity" : 400,
                "unit" : "ml"
            },
            {
                "ingredient" : "Jus de citron",
                "quantity" : 2
            },
            {
                "ingredient" : "Crème de coco",
                "quantity" : 2,
                "unit" : "cuillères à soupe"
            },
            {
                "ingredient" : "Sucre",
                "quantity" : 30,
                "unit" : "grammes"
            },
            {
                "ingredient": "Glaçons"
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

```
    <input class="input" />

    <script>
        const input = document.querySelector(".input")
        async function getRecipes() {
            const response = await (await fetch("./recipes.json")).json();
            const recipes = response.recipes;
            return ({ recipes: [...recipes] });
        };

        function filter(recipes) {
            input.addEventListener("input", () => {
                var filteredRecipes = recipes.filter(recipe => {
                    return recipe.ingredients.ingredient.toLowerCase().includes(input.value.toLowerCase())
                })
                console.log(filteredRecipes)
            })
        }

        async function init() {
            const { recipes } = await getRecipes();
            filter(recipes)
        }

        init()
    </script>
```

This error is coming to the console :

> index.html:23 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading 'toLowerCase')

which is completely fine since each ingredient isn't an ingredient. I tried a forEach on the ingredient's array but i couldn't get the result.

So, filteredRecipes should return here, or my recipe, or an empty array.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Since `recipe.ingredients` is an array, you have to use `.filter()` or its equivalent to check if an ingredient includes the searched text.

Change your `filter` function to something like this

```
function filter(recipes) {
    input.addEventListener("input", () => {
        var filteredRecipes = recipes.filter(recipe => {
            return recipe.ingredients.filter(({ingredient}) => ingredient.toLowerCase().includes(input.value.toLowerCase())).length > 0
        })
        console.log(filteredRecipes)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by the "await" in front of the fetch in the init function. Try it like so;

```
async function init() {
        const { recipes } = getRecipes().then(res => filter(res.recipes))
        .catch(err => //catch any error
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're binding an event listener on the input every time you filter.

You only need to set it once at startup.

Also to provide a more verbose alternative:

```
function filter_recipes(recipes, value) {
   let ans = []
   let filter = value.toLowerCase()
   
   for (let recipe of recipes) {
     for (let item of recipe.ingredients) {
        if (item.ingredient.toLowerCase().includes(filter)) {
          ans.push(recipe)
        }
     }
   }
   
   return ans
}
```